# Sort Data MYSQL

Tags: php

Display result based on score DESC.

I have table with 4 columns, what I want is show result order by score DESC.

```
id   t1   t2   t3   t4
----------------------
1    10   20   30   40
2    6    10   15   30
```

Sum of 4 columns and sort by DESC.

```
$q = "SELECT sum(t1+t2+t3+t4) AS point FROM scores ORDER BY point DESC"; //not working
```

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: what is not working? what error is returned?

Comment: looks fine to me. can you print what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT id, SUM(t1+t2+t3+t4) AS point
FROM scores
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY point DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 $q = "SELECT t1+t2+t3+t4 AS point FROM scores ORDER BY t1+t2+t3+t4 DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT SUM(t1+ t2+ t3+ t4) as sum_t FROM point GROUP BY id ORDER BY sum_t DESC;
```

Comment: This is right. You need group by clause in ur query.:)

Comment: I think he want the SUM of every row.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `SUM()` without a `GROUP BY` clause.

But it seems you really don't want to use `SUM()` at all, as the result you are looking for, is a simple addition:

```
SELECT (t1+t2+t3+t4) AS point FROM scores ORDER BY point DESC
```

Comment: Got 6 downvotes for the same answer. :)

Comment: @b0s3 Not from me :-) But looking at your answer, you still have `SUM()` without `GROUP BY` so that will give you a mysql error.

Comment: No that was producing different output. Updated the answer..

Comment: @b0s3 Must be a different version, on an old test server I get an error if I try to do that.

Comment: @b0s3 Anyway, it seems the OP was looking for something else, hard to tell with 2 example rows...

Comment: That was unclear. Just took a guess. :)

Comment: @b0s3 It's even worse, `SUM(...) ... GROUP BY id` will give you exactly the same result as our answers, you're just doing more unnecessary stuff. Assuming that the id is the primary key / unique of course.